# CSS Background Position when using :target

Tags: javascript, html, css, target, background-position

Ok so I've done some looking around and couldn't find a good enough answer to this question.

Basically what I'm trying to do is minimize my websites header when a button is clicked.

Heres the CSS: http://emstectest.site44.com/style.css

I've been playing around trying to get this to work but here's the problem, I'm trying to make the background image, which is a dark blue divider colour which seperates the header and body move up when the expand link is clicked (using :target on the #header style).

But I've tried something like:

```
#header:target { background-position: center -300px; }
```

but the only thing that actually moves the background image is when I do:

```
body { background: url (PATH) repeat-x center -300px; }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm holding back on using Javascript on this due to my lack of knowledge in the area; that and the fact that I want load times to be the main priority.

Another question as well as this would be: is there also a way to animate this process using -webkit- or would I have to use Javascripting again?

Thanks in advance.
- James

Comment: It's a bit hard to just work off the css. Are you able to simplify your HTML to just display the problem? Here's what I have so far from what I understand http://jsfiddle.net/78wW7/1/ I'm using `javascript` but it's very minimal so it won't impact load time.

Answer (score 0):

> #### *From the w3schools.com*
>
> **Definition and Usage**
>
> URLs with an # followed by an anchor name, link to a certain element within a document. The element being linked to is the target element.
>
> The **:target** selector can be used to style the current active target element.

[Look at an example here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target)

Your image has a fixed width of 440px so if you are trying to reduce the height if it you'll need to adjust it's proportions.